# Correct way to disable base class functionality

Tags: oop, solid-principles

Say, I have `class A` with method `M`:

```
private void M()
{
    Do1();
    Do2();
}
```

`class B` extends `A`.

**Problem:** I need `Do2()` to not to be executed when calling from an instance of `B`.

I have a couple of ideas but not sure which do not break OOP and SOLID rules.

#### Make `Do2` virtual.

```
class A
{
    protected virtual void Do2()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

class B
{
    protected override void Do2()
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

This solution looks weird to me because I override a method to "do nothing", when overriding is needed to "do something instead of something" or "do something in addition to something".

#### Create `bool` protected flag property

```
class A
{
    protected virtual NeedCallDo2
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    private void M()
    {
        Do1();

        if (NeedCallDo2)
        {
            Do2();
        }
    }
}

class B
{
    protected override NeedCallDo2
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

This solution is also not perfect but I have a control of execution flow and can decide whether to call `Do2` or not.

#### Pass constructor flag parameter

```
class A
{
    private bool needCallDo2;

    protected A(bool needCallDo2 = true)
    {
        this.needCallDo2 = needCallDo2;
    }

    private void M()
    {
        Do1();

        if (this.needCallDo2)
        {
            Do2();
        }
    }
}

class B
{
    public B()
        : base(false)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is quite abstract and doesn't allow to determine whether B should really inherit from A or if composition should be used instead. The Interface Segregation Principle may also help.

Comment: Please supply the relevant interfaces specification, not just the private methods. Also state explicitly the language you are using

Answer (score 1):

This is a trick question! Given the [solid-principles](/questions/tagged/solid-principles) tag, there is **no** correct way to disable base class functionality, since that would violate [liskov-substitution](/questions/tagged/liskov-substitution), which is the L in SOLID.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the execution logic into an *execution strategy class* where class B uses a different strategy implementation than class A.

Comment: Use of the strategy pattern seems to be reasonable as you intend to have different execution flows..